# Optimizing an algorithm subtracting first elements from last elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to optimize a slow part of a larger algorithm.

I have an array of random-looking numbers:

```
[295, 292, 208, 393, 394, 291, 182, 145, 175, 288, 71, 86, 396, 422]
```

(actual arrays are much longer), and an index: `N` (`N = 5`)

What I want to do is subtract subtract 1 from the last M elements for each of the first N elements that are smaller

So (pseudo-code):

```
for a = 1..5
  for b = 6..N
    if ary[a] < ary[b]
      ary[b]--;
```

Obviously this is a horribly inefficient O(N^2) algorithm.  I'm trying to think of a faster way to do it, but can't.  It seems like I should be able to pre-compute the values to subtract somehow, and reduce it to:

```
for a = 1..5
  // ???
for b = 6..N
  ary[b] -= ???
```

but I'm missing something.

[edit] I feel like an idiot.  I didn't properly explain what I want, fixed.

Comment: Perhaps it's more on-topic to [CR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) than SO.

Comment: What if a "last element" is larger than the sum of two "first element"s?

Comment: @greybeard -- Not sure where you got sums from?

Comment: _if the first element is smaller_ smaller than what? Or maybe you meant **least** (minimum)?

Comment: @hindmost -- The `if` in the code should make more sense.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to store original value of `ary[b]` in a variable? cause it will change with each decrement.

Comment: @hindmost -- yes, I'm cloning the array before this.  Basically when it gets here the first N pixels of an image have already been removed, so the indices following those are off by 1px for each removed pixel left of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's reorganize the loops:

```
for b = 6..N
  for a = 1..5
    if ary[a] < ary[b]
      ary[b] -= ary[a];
```

The result will be the same. But now the logic is more clear: from each element from the second part of array you subtract `ary[1]`, then `ary[2]` and so on until some `ary[a]` is bigger that what remains from `ary[b]`.

This can be optimized the following way. Calculate the cumulative sums of the first half of array: let `sum[1]=ary[1]`, `sum[2]=sum[1]+ary[2]`, `sum[3]=sum[2]+ary[3]`, and so on. This can be done in `O(N)`.

Now for each `b` you need to find such `a_last` that `sum[a_last]<ary[b]`, but `sum[a_last+1]>=ary[b]` -- this will mean that from `ary[b]` you will subtract `ary[1]+...+ary[a_last]=sum[a_last]`. You can find such `a_last` using binary search in `O(log N`), thus making the overall algorithm `O(N log N)`.

The pseudocode:

```
sum[0] = 0
for a = 1..5
    sum[a] = sum[a-1] + ary[a]
for b = 6..N
    a_last = maximal a such that sum[a]<ary[b] // use binary search
    ary[b] -= sum[a_last]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  FYI I edited the original requirements because I was an idiot and didn't type them correctly, but it doesn't change the overall algorithm, I just need a touple with an index.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Petr's solution doesn't follow the specification of the problem: we should subtract 1 (one) for each "hit", not the VALUE of ary[a].

Here's an alternative:

1. place the testvalues ary[j], j=0..N-1 in a SORTED array: sortedSmallAry[N].
2. Then run over all b, i.e. b=N, ..., Total-1, and for each ary[b]:
3. run j=0..N-1 over the sortedSmallAry, test whether sortedSmallAry[j] is smaller than ary[b], count the hits, exit as soon as it fails (because it's sorted). If N is relatively large you can use a binary search in sortedSmallAray to determine how many of its elements satisfy the condition.
4. Subtract the hitcount from ary[b].

Comment: Yeah, I changed the spec because I accidentally mis-wrote it.  His follows what I originally asked for, but it's the same general algorithm.

Thanks so much though :)

Comment: OK, welcome. I do believe, though, that for the specs currently in place (subtract 1 for each hit) you may want to consider the approach with the sorted "test-array" as I've lined out. Success!

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing now :).  The sorted array (`[208, 292, 295, 393, 394]`), gets binary searched and I just subtract the `index + 1`